# How to set bold title in Action Bar?

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-styles

I am editing the style xml trying to get the Activity title bold.

```
<style name="MyTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
</style>

<style name="MyActionBar" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:background">#81CFEB</item>
    <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
</style>
```

But only what I can set is the background color desired. I do not why the textStyle is not set to bold.

Anyone know how to solve it?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Can you please try with this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
  <style name="MyTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyTheme.MyActionBar</item>
  </style>

  <style name="MyTheme.MyActionBar"parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:titleTextStyle">@style/MyTheme.MyActionBar.TitleTextStyle</item>
  </style>

  <style name="MyTheme.MyActionBar.TitleTextStyle" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.Holo.Widget.ActionBar.Title">
    <item name="android:background">#81CFEB</item>
    <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
  </style>
</resources>
```

Answer (score 4):

For those using AppCompat, you'll need something like this:

```
<style name="MyTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyTheme.ActionBar</item>
    <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/MyTheme.ActionBar</item>
</style>

<style name="MyTheme.ActionBar" parent="Widget.AppCompat.ActionBar.Solid">
    <item name="titleTextStyle">@style/MyTheme.ActionBar.TitleTextStyle</item>
</style>

<style name="MyTheme.ActionBar.TitleTextStyle" parent="TextAppearance.AppCompat">
    <item name="android:background">#81CFEB</item>
    <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
</style>
```

Comment: Seems the first item in MyTheme.ActionBar is not needed.

Comment: I think it might be for back compat @kbitzerCZ?

Comment: I have tried to leave it out for both 6.0.1 (API 23) and 4.0.3 (API 15) and it works (hope I'm not missing something).

Comment: hmm ok, with things like `primaryColor` you sometimes need to double up like that. i've removed it based on your tests though

Answer (score -1):

There's an alternative to styling the `ActionBar` globally inside the themes file.
As the `ActionBar.setTitle()` method accepts a `CharSequence` (not just a `String`), you can style it with `Html.fromHtml()`:

Java:

```java
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 24) {
   getSupportActionBar().setTitle(Html.fromHtml("<b>" + title + "</b>", 0));
} else {
   getSupportActionBar().setTitle(Html.fromHtml("<b>" + title + "</b>"));
}
```

Kotlin:

```kotlin
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 24) {
   supportActionBar?.title = Html.fromHtml("<b>$title</b>", 0)
} else {
   supportActionBar?.title = Html.fromHtml("<b>$title</b>")
}
```

This can be useful, if you want to make the `ActionBar` title bold in only a single `Activity`.

Comment: Whilst this code snippet is welcome, and may provide some help, it would be [greatly improved if it included an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of *how* it addresses the question.  Without that, your answer has much less educational value - remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now!  Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.