# Font bold in action bar title

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-fonts

After several hours of try I give up... How to set bold font for action bar title? I have values/styles.xml below:

```
<resources>
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <!-- Background color -->
    <item name="android:background">#f1a30b</item>
    <!-- Menu text -->
    <item name="android:textColor">#ffffff</item>
    <item name="android:textStyle">bold|italic</item>
    <!-- Ttle color -->
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">#ffffff</item>
    <item name="android:titleTextStyle">@style/AppTheme.MyActionBar.TitleTextStyle</item>
</style>
<style name="AppTheme.MyActionBar.TitleTextStyle" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:background">#81CFEB</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">#000000</item>
    <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
</style>

</resources>
```

Menu text color, style and background color OK. But how to change font for title (style and text size)? I need bold and 25dp.

I understand that in manifest I should only have line `android:theme="@style/AppTheme"` for application... nothing more. Should I import some class in activity?

Answer (score 0):

You need to make override some properties for Theme which is explained **[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18969629/how-to-set-bold-title-in-action-bar)**.

Comment: Tried exactly same - this example does not work. Anyway there are some errors in syntax in this example. Android Studio does not want to process it.

Comment: Have you specified `MyTheme` to application/activity on which you are applying theme on, in `AndroidManifest.xml`?

Comment: They say it is not needed if exists in <application> tag.

Comment: Can you provide your content for `AndroidManifest.xml` & `style.xml`?

Comment: I solved it. I do not know why but it works finally.