# AppCompat: ActionBar change textColor and style?

Tags: android, android-actionbar, textcolor

I noticed a lot of people ask this question, and I change my code follow this answer:
[How to set bold title in Action Bar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18969629/how-to-set-bold-title-in-action-bar)

However, I can't change title color to red and style to bold. This is my code link in github:

https://github.com/fhlkm/TitleStyle.git

And this is my Style.xml code:

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyTheme.ActionBar</item>
    <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/MyTheme.ActionBar</item>
</style>

<style name="MyTheme.ActionBar" parent="Widget.AppCompat.ActionBar.Solid">
    <item name="titleTextStyle">@style/MyTheme.ActionBar.TitleTextStyle</item>
</style>

<style name="MyTheme.ActionBar.TitleTextStyle" parent="TextAppearance.AppCompat">
    <item name="android:background">#ff0000</item>
    <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
</style>
```

This is the screenshot:
[image]

Comment: Tell me the reason why not using Toolbar to get away with this problem??

Comment: Please don't just link to your project off-site. You need to include a [mcve] in the question itself.

Comment: @Xenolion, the reason I don't use Toolbar because this is a very big project, the github project is very little part of the project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why but after I change from parent="TextAppearance.AppCompat" to parent="Widget.AppCompat.ActionBar.TabText", the color and textStyle is changed, this is the new xml:

```
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/ActionBarCompat</item>
</style>

<style name="ActionBarCompat" parent="Widget.AppCompat.ActionBar.Solid">
    <item name="titleTextStyle">@style/titleStyle</item>
</style>

<style name="titleStyle" parent="Widget.AppCompat.ActionBar.TabText">
    <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/holo_blue_dark</item>
    <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
</style>
```